# Get unique ID values from one column then concatenate: Error 13, type mismatch

Tags: excel, vba

The code is meant to get unique ID values from one column and then on the other column concatenate it's values based on the unique IDs.

```
phishLR = defendersSht.Cells.Find(what:="*", After:=Range("A1"), LookAt:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Row
Dim dc As Object
Dim inputArray As Variant
Dim k As Long

tempEIDCN = phishLC + 1
tempCampaignsCN = phishLC + 2
'Copy values onto temp columns to make them side by side (temp solution until I figure out how to do it with separate columns
defendersSht.Range(Cells(1, tempEIDCN).Address, Cells(phishLR, tempEIDCN).Address).Value2 = _
                                                                                          defendersSht.Range(Cells(1, eidPhishCN).Address, Cells(phishLR, eidPhishCN).Address).Value2
defendersSht.Range(Cells(1, tempCampaignsCN).Address, Cells(phishLR, tempCampaignsCN).Address).Value2 = _
                                                                                                      defendersSht.Range(Cells(1, phishAlarmCN).Address, Cells(phishLR, phishAlarmCN).Address).Value2

Set dc = New Dictionary
inputArray = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(defendersSht.Range(ColLett(tempEIDCN) & "2:" & ColLett(tempCampaignsCN) & phishLR).Value)

'Assuming only have two columns - otherwise need two loops
For k = LBound(inputArray, 2) To UBound(inputArray, 2)
    If Not dc.Exists(inputArray(1, k)) Then
        dc.Add inputArray(1, k), inputArray(2, k)
    Else
        dc.Item(inputArray(1, k)) = dc.Item(inputArray(1, k)) & ", " & inputArray(2, k)
    End If
Next k
'Clear values currently in column
defendersSht.Range(Cells(2, eidPhishCN).Address, Cells(phishLR, eidPhishCN).Address).ClearContents
defendersSht.Range(Cells(2, phishAlarmCN).Address, Cells(phishLR, phishAlarmCN).Address).ClearContents

'Output into sheet
defendersSht.Range(ColLett(eidPhishCN) & "2").Resize(UBound(dc.Keys) + 1) = Application.Transpose(dc.Keys)
defendersSht.Range(ColLett(phishAlarmCN) & "2").Resize(UBound(dc.Items) + 1) = Application.Transpose(dc.Items)

'Delete Temp Columns
defendersSht.Columns(tempCampaignsCN).ClearContents
defendersSht.Columns(tempEIDCN).ClearContents

Set dc = Nothing
```

I get

> type mismatch

at:

```
If Not dc.Exists(inputArray(1, k)) Then
```

As a bonus, I'm copying the columns to the next available column in order to keep them together as I can't figure out how to do this with the columns not being consecutive.

Comment: Maybe the array value at that index is causing an issue, Try forcing it to be a string `If Not dc.Exists(CStr(inputArray(1, k))) Then`

Comment: I do that and then the very next line gives me the same issue. I apply CStr to that line as well and then excel just quits on me abruptly.

Comment: What is the value of `inputArray(1, k)` right before it crashes? Are you able to step through and watch the value?

Comment: Wait. I tried it again but this time I applied ```CStr``` to all of the ```inputArray(1,k)```. It worked. I can't believe I've spent so much time on this for such a simple fix. Thank you so much. If you want to post as an answer (hopefully with the added bonus I asked for) I will accept the answer.

Comment: I can't even explain myself properly to make a real answer. I couldn't tell you what the problem was, I just know that in my own projects, adding `CStr` fixes problems with Dictionaries.

Comment: Gotcha. Well, thank you. If someone else posts the answer with the added bonus I'll give them credit. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Process()

    Const eidPhishCN = 1
    Const phishAlarmCN = 5

    Dim defendersSht As Worksheet, lastrow As Long, r As Long
    Dim dc, v, k As String
    Dim ar1, ar2, t0 As Single: t0 = Timer
    Set dc = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    Set defendersSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Defenders")
    With defendersSht
        lastrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, eidPhishCN).End(xlUp).Row
        ar1 = .Cells(1, eidPhishCN).Resize(lastrow)
        ar2 = .Cells(1, phishAlarmCN).Resize(lastrow)
        For r = 2 To lastrow
            k = Trim(ar1(r, 1))
            v = Trim(ar2(r, 1))
            If dc.Exists(k) Then
                dc.Item(k) = dc.Item(k) & ", " & v
            Else
                dc.Add k, v
            End If
        Next
        
        ' clear existing
        .Cells(2, eidPhishCN).Resize(lastrow - 1).ClearContents
        .Cells(2, phishAlarmCN).Resize(lastrow - 1).ClearContents
        
        ' save unique values
        .Cells(2, eidPhishCN).Resize(dc.Count) = Application.Transpose(dc.keys)
        .Cells(2, phishAlarmCN).Resize(dc.Count) = Application.Transpose(dc.items)
        
    End With
   
    MsgBox lastrow - 1 & " rows scanned", vbInformation, "Took " & Format(Timer - t0, "0.0 secs")
     
End Sub
```

Comment: This worked great. One question though. I changed dc to an object. Will it work as a string? It worked as an object. I didn't even try it as a string. Either way, this works and you managed to do it without the need for temp columns. Perfect. Thanks!

Comment: @DanCue dc is a dictionary object so has to be variant or object not a string. v can be declared as string ideally if using trim.

Comment: Am I reading your code wrong then? Are you not declaring dc as a string in your code?

Comment: @DanCue No, `Dim dc, v, k As String` declares dc and v as variant as the default and only k as a string. Sorry if it confused you, better as  `Dim dc as object, v as string, k As String`.You can use `Dim i, j, k As Integer` in Visual Basic but not VBA (Visual Basic For Applications) in Office.

Comment: gotcha. Thanks for clearing that up!